# Conversion from string "" to 'Double' is not valid. VB Form

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub STRPoints_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles STRPoints.ValueChanged
    If STRPoints.Value >= 10 Then
        STRScorelbl.Text = STRScorelbl.Text + (STRPoints.Value Mod 10)
    ElseIf STRPoints.Value < 10 Then
        STRScorelbl.Text = STRScorelbl.Text - (10 - STRPoints.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

The code is supposed to display a number onto the screen as a label, said number is affected by 2 different things. Firstly a radio button which adds +2 to it and the other a UpDownNumeric box which adds it's value (Mod 10) to the base number which is also 10 incidentally.

The error is:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.'

I have read the error but even after casting the things in roughly 100 different ways I just can't seem to fix it. Thanks retroactively for anyone who can help and explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of your file.  Numbers and text are different things

Comment: *`Even after casting the things in roughly 100 different ways I just can't seem to fix it.`* I do not see this in the above code. Also an empty string can't be casted to a double, so you need to check if the `StringIsNullOrEmpty` before doing a cast and or use `Double.TryParse` function...

Comment: Hey, I am aware that numbers and text are different things as such I have tried converting the STRScoreslbl.Text into an integer then the whole thing into a String but that didn't work either. Like this: STRScorelbl.Text = CStr(CInt(STRScorelbl.Text) - (10 - STRPoints.Value)) 
I have changed the 'Option Strict' to On but that didn't work.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Hey the string has the value of 10 upon start so it's most definitely not empty if that's what you mean. If not please do clarify.

Comment: Your error message shows the string you were trying to convert: `System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.'` an empty string ("") can not be converted to a double

Comment: have you tried adding a break point and looking at the value of `STRScorelbl.Text` before casting it?

Comment: The code uses the + operator to combine a string and a number.  There are two ways that could be done, one works and one doesn't.  Reason through which one was used.  It is different for the - operator, now there is only one way that could be done.  Reason through why that's the case.  If this sounds terribly confusing, it should, then don't try to combine a string and a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`STRScorelbl.Text` is empty. So when you have this code:

```
STRScorelbl.Text = STRScorelbl.Text +
```

You're already in trouble, before we even know what's on the other side of that operator. No matter how you try to cast or convert the empty string, you're stuck.

If you had turned `Option Strict On`, as any good project will do, this error would be easier to spot, because the compiler would have complained at you and underlined the mistake in the Visual Studio editor. Leaving Option Strict Off is extremely poor practice.

After turning on Option Strict and fixing any other helpful compiler errors this change produces, you can fix it like this:

```
Private Sub STRPoints_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles STRPoints.ValueChanged
    Dim OriginalValue As Double = 0.0
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(STRScorelbl.Text) Then OriginalValue = Double.Parse(STRScorelbl.Text)

    If STRPoints.Value >= 10 Then
        OriginalValue += (STRPoints.Value Mod 10)
    Else
        OriginalValue -= (STRPoints.Value Mod 10)
    End If
    STRScorelbl.Text = OriginalValue.ToString()
End Sub
```

More than that, I wouldn't use a label control, which is text, as the authoritative storage for numeric data. Instead I would have a property like this:

```
Private _Score As Double = 0.0
Public Property Score As Double
    Get
       Return _Score
    End Get
    Set
       _Score = value
       STRScorelbl.Text = _Score.ToString()
    End Set
End Property
```

Then you can simplify the ValueChanged() method:

```
Private Sub STRPoints_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles STRPoints.ValueChanged
    If STRPoints.Value >= 10 Then
        Score += (STRPoints.Value Mod 10)
    Else
        Score -= (STRPoints.Value Mod 10)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try with the val() function, example:

```
Private Sub STRPoints_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
STRPoints.ValueChanged
    If val(STRPoints.Value) >= 10 Then
        STRScorelbl.Text = val(STRScorelbl.Text) + (val(STRPoints.Value) Mod 10)
    ElseIf STRPoints.Value < 10 Then
        STRScorelbl.Text = val(STRScorelbl.Text) - (10 - val(STRPoints.Value))
    End If
End Sub
```