# Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid. on below code ListBox4.Items.Add(TxUP.Text * TxBuyOrder.Text)

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBuy.Click
    If TxBuyOrder.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("How Much You Want " & TxBuyPName.Text, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    Else

        If TxCname.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter Customer Name")
        Else
            ListBox1.Items.Add(TxBuyPName.Text)
            ListBox2.Items.Add(TxUP.Text)
            ListBox3.Items.Add(TxBuyOrder.Text)
            ListBox4.Items.Add(TxUP.Text * TxBuyOrder.Text)
            TxBuyOrder.Text = ""
            TxBuyPName.Text = ""
            TxBuyPPrice.Text = ""
            CName.Text = TxCname.Text.ToUpper
            CAddress.Text = TxCAddress.Text.ToUpper
            Cphone.Text = TxCPhone.Text

            LdATE.Text = Today.Date

        End If
    End If
    ToolStripTextBox1.Focus()
    ToolStripTextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: The very first thing you should do is turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties and fix all the typing errors it flags.  You should also set it `On` in the IDE options, so that it will be `On` by default for all future projects.  On the line in question, you are performing a mathematical operation, i.e. multiplication, on two `Strings`.  That's not possible.  Those `Strings` need to be converted to numbers in order to perform arithmetic.  That should be done explicitly, which `Option Strict On` will force you to do.  In your code, you're relying on the system to do it implicitly.

Comment: @jmcilhinney is correct. You are relying on implecit casting, don't rely on that, it can behave in ways you may not want.

Comment: Turning `Option Strict On` and converting explicitly still won't solve your problem, but hopefully it will make it more plain what the problem is.  You are converting text to numbers.  For that to make sense, the text has to contain characters that represent a number.  The error message is telling you that one of your `TextBoxes` is empty.  How does is make sense to convert and empty `String` to a number?  It doesn't, and that's the issue.  You should be validating any data like that before using it.  You're doing a bit of validating but not enough.

Comment: i did Option Strict On...... dint work i converted string to number by Convert.ToInt32(TxBuyOrder.Text) dint work,....... how to solve this? how to modify the the code ! thank you for replaying...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion from string "" to 'Double' is not valid. VB Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52897964/conversion-from-string-to-double-is-not-valid-vb-form)

Comment: ... must be the latest homework question.

Comment: "dint work" tells us nothing.  In what way did it not work?  Be specific!  Please show the code where you converted to integer and then did the multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

If the text in your text boxes is not a number of is empty .TryParse will keep your program from crashing.

```
Dim num1, num2 As Double
If Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, num1) Then
      If Double.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, num2) Then
         ListBox1.Items.Add(num1 * num2)
      End If
End If
```